# How to union tables in hierarchi

Tags: sql-server, database

How to create Hierarchi like this:

```
.Firm №1  
   .Branch Office №1
   .Branch Office №2
      .Department №1
.Firm №2  
   .Branch Office №1
      .Department №1
      .Department №2
```

I create 3 tables: Firms,Branch, Depart. Relations between tables  like this: http://www.programmersforum.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=72666&d=1422349644

```
CREATE TABLE "Firms"     
( "ID"  INTEGER NOT NULL,  
  "NAME"    VARCHAR(30),  
 PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);


CREATE TABLE "Branch" 
(  
  "ID"  INTEGER NOT NULL,    
  "NAME"    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,    
  "PARENT_ID"   INTEGER NOT NULL,    
 PRIMARY KEY ("ID")    
);  
ALTER TABLE "branch" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("PARENT_ID") REFERENCES "firms"("ID");  

CREATE TABLE "Depart"   
(
  "ID"  INTEGER NOT NULL,  
  "NAME"    VARCHAR(30),  
  "PARENT_ID"   INTEGER NOT NULL,  
  "PARENT_ID2"  INTEGER NOT NULL,  
 PRIMARY KEY ("ID")  
);  
ALTER TABLE "Depart" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("PARENT_ID") REFERENCES "firms" ("ID");  
ALTER TABLE "Depart" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("PARENT_ID2") REFERENCES "branch" ("ID");
```

How to write query,which selects firms,branchs, departaments with their ParentsIDs to create hierarchy above?

```
Select  id, name, null as parent_id from firms  
union  
Select  id, name, parent_id from branch  
union  
Select  id, name, parent_id from depart  
don't works- Error:"Data Type Unknown"
```

Comment: Put an example of what you expect from your query.

Comment: And probably you should learn about JOIN before trying to do that ...

Comment: ID, ParentID, Name  and with these I want to build hierarchic tree

Comment: I know that I must add Level field in query to differ from which table are data selected, but don't know how to write query

Comment: I think I got your problem - probably the error comes from the fact that it cannot infer the data type from the null value.

Comment: You might check the following (I have no SQL Server to check): 1) `select id, name, 0 as parent_id` or 2) change the `parent_id` column from `NOT NULL` to `NULL` for the two tables.

Comment: **BeS**, You are right! I change null with 0 and it works. But...query gives me parentID from 3 tables. For example: id "1", name "ltd ABC",  ParentId 1; id "1", name "Branch #1",  ParentId 1;  id "1", name "Departament #1",  ParentId 1 etc. With this query it's impossible to build tree because  they have the same ParentID  from 3 different tables. How  differ records with parentID or with other marks, from tables they are what?

Comment: see picture:    http://fastpic.ru/view/57/2015/0128/503708a840739bd00961e9560665c6be.png.html

Answer (score 0):

My Problem resolved:                                                                          `select 0*100000 +id, name, 0*0 as parent_id from firms
union
select 1*100000 +id, name, 0*100000+parent_id from branch
union
select 2*100000 +id, name, 1*100000+parent_id from depart`